# Lambda not able to execute the aws sdk API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am trying to create a lambda function which will check if a particular repository exist in codecommit.
Lamda service role is having admin priviledge. Below is the code.
The lambda is unable to call getRepository method. It is niether giving any exception nor passing. Any help on this?
console.log("Before calling cc") This is last printed statement. After that I am not getting any success or error log.

```
const CloudFormation = require('aws-sdk/clients/cloudformation');
const Codecommit = require('aws-sdk/clients/codecommit');
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    try{
        console.log("event",event);
    console.log("event",JSON.stringify(event));
    var repositoryName = event.detail.repositoryName;
    var cfn = new CloudFormation({ 
    region: "ap-northeast-1"
    });
    var cc = new Codecommit({ 
    region: "ap-northeast-1"
    });
    const stackName = repositoryName+"-infra-stack";
    var cloneUrl;
    console.log("RepositoryName"+repositoryName);
    console.log("StackName"+stackName);
    var codeCommitParam = {
        repositoryName: repositoryName
      };
    try{
        console.log("Before calling cc")
        cc.getRepository(codeCommitParam, function(err, data) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        }else {
            console.log(data.repositoryMetadata.cloneUrlHttp);
            cloneUrl=data.repositoryMetadata.cloneUrlHttp; 
            console.log("Clone url "+cloneUrl);        
            checkStackDescription();
        }   
      });
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample event?

Comment: what timeout for the lambda?

Comment: yes.. This is the event  `{
  version: '0',
  id: '***',
  'detail-type': 'CodeCommit Repository State Change',
  source: 'aws.codecommit',
  account: '***',
  time: '2020-08-05T07:40:51Z',
  region: '***',
  resources: [
    '*'
  ],
  detail: {
    callerUserArn: '***',
    commitId: ***
    event: 'referenceUpdated',
    oldCommitId: '****',
    referenceFullName: 'refs/heads/master',
    referenceName: 'master',
    referenceType: 'branch',
    repositoryId: '***',
    repositoryName: 'custom-ui-pipeline'
  }
}`

Comment: @NghiaDo Timeout is 4 mins.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is coming down to the JavaScript in the Lambda being invoked asynchronously so the Lambda is finishing invoking before the callback processes the response.

Try updating to use this synchronously by updating to the below syntax.

```
console.log("Before calling cc")
let result = await cc.getRepository(codeCommitParam).promise();

console.log(result);
```

Be aware that `result` could either be an error or valid response.

Comment: Try is properly closed with a Catch later in the code. Regarding lambda timeout, i have increased it to 4 mins. Also, Lambda is not within any VPC.

Comment: Hmm ok, I think its actually the async running on your Lambdas NodeJS callback. Updated to make it synchronous and I can view in the logs. Updated answer

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Thanks for helping me out here.:)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Comment: instead of using await, I removed top async. Hope this will not create any problem in lambda.

Comment: The only thing to be aware of is that if anything requires the results of the code commit code outside of the callback it probably won't have access to that information yet